# Python Flask RequestParser

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am learning flask Restful API, where I came upon RequestParser
wherein my example includes

```
data_put = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
data_put.add_argument("username",type=str,help="Username not provided",location="json",required=True)
data_put.add_argument("new_password",type=str,help="New password not provided", location="json", required=True )
```

this above code snippet works great with username and new_password parameter and returns error message if any, as

```
    {
    "message": {
        "username": "Username not provided",
    }
}
```

this is great.

But is it possible to insert a user defined value into the response message,
for example, can I get a response as

```
{
    "message": {
        "username": "Username not provided",
        "error_code": 1000
    }
}
```

where value of error code will be a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can remove the required from the .add_argument line, and the in the class, where you get the post/get after you do
`args = data_put.parseargs`()
You can check if there is the username in the args

```
if args["username"]:
return {"message": "Wrong username"}
```

And return a HTTP status or error code